# How to save 'hidden-fields' value and change the button text 'Join' to 'Joined' Using AJAX, PHP & MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a small email subscription system. I have created a form and added two hidden fields in it named 'uid' and 'gid' respectively. The 'uid' hidden field contains the value of the current logged in user and gid contains the id of the email contents a user wants. But, I am facing problem to save the data and change the text of the button after AJAX call. Please help me with the code. I am new in AJAX so it will be helpful for me if you can comment each line.

Problems: [1] The data(s) are not passing to the test.php [2] I want to change the button text Join to Joined. But I don't know how to do it

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function save_details() 
    {
        var uid = $("#uid").val(data);
        var gid = $("#gid").val(data);
            var dataString = 'uid='+ uid + '&gid=' + gid + '&page=choose';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/test.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() 
                {
                    $("#signup_status").html('<h5><img src="assets/img/loading.gif"> Please wait...</h5>');
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div align="center" id="signup_status"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $get;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="gid" id="gid" value="1234569877896541235">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onClick="save_details();">Join</button>
```

Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: You've said you have a problem, but not described what the problem actually is

Comment: What is the issue ? What kind of debugging you have approached ?

Comment: Problems:
[1] The data(s) are not passing to the test.php
[2] I want to change the button text Join to Joined. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jquery, you have something wrong:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function save_details(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
    var uid = $("#uid").val();//without data
    var gid = $("#gid").val();//without data
```

and if you want :

```
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onClick="save_details();">Join</button>
```

To:
      Joined

you must add this in success:

```
  success: function(response) {
    $('.btn').html('Joined').attr('onClick', '');//better with id
    $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
  }
```

Try like this, and in your php ajax/test.php", you'll "save":

```
 $uid = $_POST['uid'];
 $gid = $_POST['gid'];
```

Are you sure that $get have value???

Comment: Thank you! But still, it's not working. And how to change the button text after submission.